# Apache in front of Tomcat not working

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jboss, ajp

I am using the following example file: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/ and have deployed it on Tomcat.

I want to put Apache in front of Tomcat. I have the following config on my Tomcat's server.xml:

```
    <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8010" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

My Apache is running on port 80, and my workers.properties looks as follows:

```
worker.list=jboss,tomcat

worker.jboss.port=8009
worker.jboss.host=127.0.0.1
worker.jboss.type=ajp13

worker.tomcat.port=8010
worker.tomcat.host=127.0.0.1
worker.tomcat.type=ajp13
```

Note that I also have JBoss running. Then my uriworkermap.properties looks as follows:

```
/App/*=jboss
/sample/*=tomcat
/sample=tomcat
/sample/=tomcat
```

The JBoss config works fine. If I go to http://localhost:8081/sample/ my webpage is displayed. But if I go to http://localhost:80/sample/ I get a
**The Webpage cannot be found** error. What am I doing wrong?

This is what http://localhost:8081/sample/ looks like:
[image]

Comment: I assume you have a servlet HelloWorld for Tomcat to deploy. Has it deployed HellowWorld?

Comment: You mean deployed as in a WAR file?

Comment: Yes. typically you would have war that Tomcat would unpack.

Comment: To make it easier to understand, I am using this sample WAR file https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/ which I have deployed on the webapps folder of Tomcat

Answer (score -1):

you can't run a java app on apache web server. you need a servlet container like tomcat to run a java app. If you want to use apache as a gateway to your app deployed at tomcat, you can have some static file or cgi script in your apache server and that script or html file could call your app deployed at tomcat. URL http://localhost:80/sample/ is not working because it's expecting a file name sample in your apache's www (usually) directory and your probably don't have that file in there.

Comment: Right. The java app runs on a servlet container in Tomcat. The idea is to put Apache in front of Tomcat (I believe a proxy is the right terminology) so it handles static content.

Comment: To make it easier to understand, I am using this sample WAR file http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/ which I have deployed on the webapps folder of Tomcat. I have edited my post to reflect this

Comment: Looking at your URL's, it would not work the way you expecting it work. you can have a gateway on apache server to your tomcat. For that you need to setup your apache server and provide your static file or script in proper directory and proper access. what is sample in http://localhost:80/sample/?
sample is supposed to be some static file or script residing in your www folder of your apache installation. All I see is you are expecting apache to behave like tomcat.

Comment: For now, yes. I just want apache to serve as a proxy for tomcat so I can access localhost:8081/sample/ from localhost:80/sample. I understand that in order for apache to serve the static content, I need to configure a virtual host pointing apache to the location of the static content. But first I want to just behave like tomcat and act as a proxy. I have added a picture on my post to show you what the site looks like.

Comment: you have to do it the way apache works. In apache, localhost:80/sample does not work the way it works in tomcat. since you just wanted it as a gateway, so you should have some html file or cgi script named sample in your www folder and that script should call your tomcat like  localhost:8081/sample